# Problema con delegados y eventos

Tags: c#, hilos, eventos, backgroundworker, delegados

Quiero usar un evento y un delegado, para escribir texto en un RichTextBox. Estoy usando hilos, con el BackGroundWorker y necesito el delegado. He encontrado este ejemplo, que me funciona perfectamente, es 1 clase, que crea el delegado, el evento y la funcion del multiplo, y otro archivo que es el form.
**Clase work:**

```
    namespace SolucionRichTextBox
{
    class Work
    {
        //delegado
        public delegate void work(string notificacion);
        //evento
        public event work working;
        //metodo trabajando
        public void trabajando()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                working(i.ToString());
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

**Y el archivo del form, que es este.**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnEmpezar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Work w = new Work();
            //Delegado que tiene el metodo notificar
            w.working += new Work.work(notificar);
            //Creamos un nuevo hilo y cuando se crea llama a la funcion trabajando
            Thread t = new Thread(w.trabajando);
            //Inicia el hilo
            t.Start();

        }
        //Metodo que se ejecutara en otro hilo y escribe en el box
        public void notificar(string notificacion)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.Text += notificacion +"\n"));
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora lo intento extrapolar a mi problema real, y no entiendo porque no funciona. He hecho esto.

```
//Escribir con un delegado en el richTextBox
        //Creo un delegado de la clase
        private delegate void delegado(string notificaciones);

        //Creo un evento del delegado
        private event delegado Evento;

        //Asocio el evento al metodo notificar
        Evento += new delegado(notificar);

        public void notificar(string notificacion)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                Invoke(new Action(() => BoxText.Text += notificacion + "\n"));
        }
        //Boton enviar. Empieza la funcion en segundo plano, y al llamar a RunWorker llama a Dowork.
        private void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                //inicia el proceso
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

***Evento += new delegado(notificar);*** Esta linea me da error. El nombre Evento no existe en el contexto actual. El notificador new no es apto para este elemento y (notificar) el tipo de nombres no se identifico.
Llevo dias y varias preguntas por aqui, y esta me ha parecido la mejor solucion, pero llevo con C# 2 semanas y nunca habia manejado hilos(me estan dando mucho dolor de cabeza). Y lo que realmente quiero, es tener la GUI en segundo plano y cuando acabe, que muestre en un RTB, ya ha terminado, o los errores que va produciendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo puedes puedes subscribir un delegado o metodo a un evento *dentro de un metodo* o *en el constructor*. No puedes hacerlo en la declaracion de la clase:

```
NombreConstructor(){    
    //Asocio el evento al metodo notificar
    Evento += new delegado(notificar); // funciona perfectamente
}

public void notificar(string notificacion){
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(new Action(() => BoxText.Text += notificacion + "\n"));
}
```

Codigo completo:

```
NombreConstructor(){    
    //Asocio el evento al metodo notificar
    Evento += new delegado(notificar);
}

//Escribir con un delegado en el richTextBox
//Creo un delegado de la clase
private delegate void delegado(string notificaciones);

//Creo un evento del delegado
private event delegado Evento;

public void notificar(string notificacion){
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(new Action(() => BoxText.Text += notificacion + "\n"));
}
//Boton enviar. Empieza la funcion en segundo plano, y al llamar a RunWorker llama a Dowork.
private void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true){
        //inicia el proceso
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Donde `NombreConstructor`, es el nombre del constructor de la clase.

Comment: Gracias, sabia que seria un error simple.